# how to intercept CRUD in sqlalchemy based app?

Tags: python, database, orm, sqlalchemy, crud

I am running an app that using sqlalchemy to access db layer.   now I need to get all the insert, update, delete operation, I wrote db operation in two many places and seems it will be very risky to change those code.  Is there anyway that I could just change sqlalchemy's code and capture all "insert, update, delete" operations?

I tried to find execute, but there was too many definitions:

```
lib/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.5.3-py2.6.egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py
463:    def execute(self, *multiparams, **params):
500:    def execute(self, object, *multiparams, **params):
819:    def execute(self, object, *multiparams, **params):
1200:    def execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params):
1280:        def execute(self, object, *multiparams, **params):
1808:    def execute(self):
1855:    def execute_string(self, stmt, params=None):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `before_execute` and other events documented in [Connection Events](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/events.html#connection-events). Sample from documentation verbatim:

```
from sqlalchemy import event, create_engine

def before_execute(conn, clauseelement, multiparams, params):
    log.info("Received statement: %s" % clauseelement)

engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/test')
event.listen(engine, "before_execute", before_execute)
```